# Fill empty dates in a matrix SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to find a way to fill dates that have no data in a matrix.
What I have right now is below

[image]

But I want to show all the dates in between as well.
I have tried several different iif statements but I either get errors or no change.

```
SELECT ee.No, TTMain.CustFn, me.Date_Opened AS [I Open], me.Date_Closed AS [I Sch Close], TTMain.ttfn00, 
   ee.Cls_Date AS [Actual Close Date], ee.Open_Date, TTMain.Project
FROM   GreatAmerican_Data.dbo.Marketing_Escrow AS me INNER JOIN
   GreatAmerican_Data.dbo.Escmst_Escrow AS ee ON me.File_Number = ee.No     INNER JOIN
   ttMain AS TTMain ON ee.No = TTMain.ZeroZerottfn
WHERE  (ee.Branch = '018') AND (me.Date_Opened Between '2/1/16' AND GETDATE()) AND (ee.Status_Date IS NULL)
ORDER BY [I Sch Close]
```

[Data returned with vendor names and account number blacked out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99wpF.jpg)

Comment: Share a sample of your dataset.

Comment: By data set do you mean my query or the data it returns

Comment: I mean data it returns, but I think it can be solved at query level too so query could be useful.

Comment: Updated with query and data

Comment: If you generate dates that are not included in the dataset they must be null for every row what is the reason for that? Supposing you want to see dates from Feb 03 to Feb 08 what values you want it shows for every row?

Comment: You will need some sort of calendar like set as @Marco Bong suggests in their answer.  If you have a table that has the missing dates somewhere you could select them out of that as well either way you need to bring those missing dates into your final dataset and set everything except whatever fields maps to `Client` and your needed date fields as `NULL` or `0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare Months table with full date of month

Example:

```
declare @tbMonth as Table (DayOfMonth nvarchar (10))
insert into @tbMonth ('01 Feb')
insert into @tbMonth ('02 Feb')
insert into @tbMonth ('03 Feb')
insert into @tbMonth ('04 Feb')
```

... and so on

2. union `@tbMonth` with your output table, and group by `[DayOfMonth]`, 
   Sum([Your required columns])
3. Done.