# How to count number of logins every minute and return zero if the result is null

Tags: sql-server

It appears there is a lot of information out there regarding this topic, but I don't have enough SQL knowledge to apply it to my situation.

**This is the query I'm currently working with:**

```
/* Number of successful logins per minute for a given date range */
SELECT
         DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, AuditMessage.EventDateTime), 0) AS Time, 
         COUNT(AuditMessage.EventTypeCodeUid) AS CountSuccessfulLoginAttemptsPerMinute
FROM     IRWSDB.dbo.AuditMessage
JOIN     AuditEventTypeCode
ON       AuditEventTypeCode.EventTypeCodeUid = AuditMessage.EventTypeCodeUid
WHERE    AuditEventTypeCode.DisplayName = 'Login' 
         AND AuditMessage.EventDateTime >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-03-03 00:00:00', 120) 
         AND AuditMessage.EventDateTime <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-03-04 00:00:00', 120)
GROUP BY DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, AuditMessage.EventDateTime), 0)
ORDER BY DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, AuditMessage.EventDateTime), 0)
```

**Example Output (works as expected):**

```
          Time               CountSuccessfulLoginAttemptsPerMinute

2016-03-03 17:48:00.000        1

2016-03-03 17:49:00.000        1

2016-03-03 17:50:00.000        1

2016-03-03 17:55:00.000        2
```

**Desired Output:**

```
Time                         CountSuccessfulLoginAttemptsPerMinute

2016-03-03 17:48:00.000        1

2016-03-03 17:49:00.000        1

2016-03-03 17:50:00.000        1

2016-03-03 17:51:00.000        0

2016-03-03 17:52:00.000        0

2016-03-03 17:53:00.000        0

2016-03-03 17:54:00.000        0

2016-03-03 17:55:00.000        2
```

I tried to modify the above query to get the desired output, but every path I've gone down has been a dead end.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: You'd need to manually create the values you want, then modify your query so that you left join to the values.

Comment: you need a list of all the minutes you want shown in your result set, then LEFT join that to the COUNT.

Answer (score 1):

If your database doesn't have every min of the day, it won't be able to get desired output. Unless you backend/whatever will insert a record to your table every min or refer to this link [Fill empty dates in a matrix SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468564/fill-empty-dates-in-a-matrix-ssrs/35470738#35470738). Then you can modify your query like this

```
SELECT
         DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, AuditMessage.EventDateTime), 0) AS Time, 
         ISNULL(COUNT(AuditMessage.EventTypeCodeUid),0) AS CountSuccessfulLoginAttemptsPerMinute
FROM     IRWSDB.dbo.AuditMessage
JOIN     AuditEventTypeCode
ON       AuditEventTypeCode.EventTypeCodeUid = AuditMessage.EventTypeCodeUid
WHERE    AuditEventTypeCode.DisplayName = 'Login' 
         AND AuditMessage.EventDateTime >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-03-03 00:00:00', 120) 
         AND AuditMessage.EventDateTime <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-03-04 00:00:00', 120)
GROUP BY DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, AuditMessage.EventDateTime), 0)
ORDER BY DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, AuditMessage.EventDateTime), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to generate all minutes in the date range. To do this, you need a [Tally Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/). Then do a `LEFT JOIN` on your original query.

```
DECLARE @start  DATETIME,
        @end    DATETIME

SELECT @start = '20160303', @end = '20160304'

;WITH E1(N) AS(
    SELECT 1 FROM(VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t(N)
),
E2(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E1 a CROSS JOIN E1 b),
E4(N) AS(SELECT 1 FROM E2 a CROSS JOIN E2 b),
CteTally(N) AS(
    SELECT TOP(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @start, @end) + 1) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))
    FROM E4
),
CteMinute(dt) AS(
    SELECT  dt = DATEADD(MINUTE, N-1, @start) FROM CteTally
)
SELECT
    cm.dt AS [Time],
    ISNULL(t.cnt, 0) AS CountSuccessfulLoginAttemptsPerMinute
FROM CteMinute cm
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, am.EventDateTime), 0) AS [Time],
        COUNT(am.EventTypeUid) AS cnt
    FROM IRWSDB.dbo.AuditMessage am
    INNER JOIN AuditEventTypeCode atc
        ON atc.EventTypeCodeUid = am.EventTypeCodeUid
    WHERE
        atc.DisplayName = 'Login'
        AND am.EventDateTime >= @start
        AND am.EventDateTime <= @end
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, am.EventDateTime), 0)
) t
    ON cm.dt = t.[Time]
GROUP BY cm.dt
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use LEFT JOIN of "list of every minutes" to your current query
2nd way is to UNION ALL the current query with the "list of every minutes" and then do a SUM on the Count

There are may ways to create the "list of every minutes" like using tally/number table, recursive cte, cross join etc.

Here is a method using recursive cte

```
;with minutes as
(
    select Time = convert(datetime, '2016-03-03')
    union all
    select Time = dateadd(minute, 1, Time)
    from   minutes
    where  Time < '2016-03-05'
)
select Time
from   minues
```

Method 1 : LEFT JOIN

```
;with minutes as
(
    select Time = convert(datetime, '2016-03-03')
    union all
    select Time = dateadd(minute, 1, Time)
    from   minutes
    where  Time < '2016-03-05'
),
data as
(
    < your current query here without the order by clause> 
)
select m.Time, isnull(CountSuccessfulLoginAttemptsPerMinute, 0) as CountSuccessfulLoginAttemptsPerMinute
from   minues m
       left join data d on m.Time = d.Time
```

Method 2 : UNION ALL

```
;with minutes as
(
    select Time = convert(datetime, '2016-03-03')
    union all
    select Time = dateadd(minute, 1, Time)
    from   minutes
    where  Time < '2016-03-05'
)
select Time, sum(CountSuccessfulLoginAttemptsPerMinute) as CountSuccessfulLoginAttemptsPerMinute
FROM
(
     < your current query here without the order by clause> 
     union all
     select Time, 0 as CountSuccessfulLoginAttemptsPerMinute
     from   mintues
) d
group by Time
```